# How to invert LAS files

Tags: 3d, las, point-cloud, lastools, scene-layer-package

I have a bunch of LAS files which are supposed to show data underwater but the depth (z) is poisitive rather than negative so they are inverted. I'm looking for the fastest way to invert/flip them on the z axis - effectively multiply the z value by -1.

I have downloaded lastools and tried using las2las with the z_scale set to -1, but this doesnt seem to do anything.

```
arcpy..lastransform(r"\\location\file.las", "scale_z", -1, '', None, '', None, '', "las", r"filename.las", "\\\\folderlocation", "_invert", '', True)
```

Am I doing something wrong with this tool, or should I be using another tool?

Once I have the LAS files I'm creating pointcloud slpks, so if there is a method of flipping these that's even better.